# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'productcategory_id' into field. Choices are: country, country_id, id, name, vendor?

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to use here Django dependent dropdown list. But at the same time, the error occurred. If I make an ajax request click the product category and the dependent dropdown not working togetherly and cannot make an ajax request shows an error. How to resolve this error? Can please someone help me to clear this issue.

Models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 class ProductCategory(models.Model): 
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

 class SubCategory(models.Model):
     country = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name

 class Vendor(models.Model):
     designer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
     design_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     description = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
     productcategory = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
     null=True)
     subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.designer_name
```

forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from .models import Vendor, ProductCategory, SubCategory

 class DesignerForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Vendor
         descr = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )        
         fields = ('designer_name','design_name', 'description', 'productcategory', 'subcategory')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.none()

    if 'productcategory' in self.data:
        try:
            productcategory_id = int(self.data.get('productcategory'))
            self.fields['subcategory'].queryset = SubCategory.objects.filter(productcategory_id=productcategory_id).order_by('name')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            pass  # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty City queryset
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['subcategory'].queryset = self.instance.productcategory.subcategory_set.order_by('name')
```

Views.py

```
 from .models import *
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from .forms import *



 def Products(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = DesignerForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
         return redirect('Products')
    else:
         form = DesignerForm()
    return render(request, 'jinja2/products.jinja',{'form': form})



 def ajax_load_subcategories(request):
     productcategory_id = request.GET.get('productcategory')
     subcategories = 
    SubCategory.objects.filter(productcategory_id=productcategory_id).order_by('name')
      return render(request, 'jinja2/city_dropdown_list_options.jinja', {'subcategories': 
     subcategories})
```

admin.py

```
 from django.contrib import admin
 from boutique_store.models import Vendor, ProductCategory, SubCategory


 # Register your models here.
 admin.site.register(ProductCategory)
 admin.site.register(SubCategory)
 admin.site.register(Vendor)
```

urls.py

```
 from django.urls import include, path
 from . import views

 urlpatterns = [

     path('add/', views.Products, name='Products'),
     path('ajax/load_subcategories/', views.ajax_load_subcategories, 
    name='ajax_load_subcategories'),  # <-- this one here
 ]
```

products.jinja

```
 {% block content %}

   <h2>Person Form</h2>

   <form method="post" id="designerForm" data-subcategories-url="{% URL 
 'ajax_load_subcategories' %}" novalidate>
     {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
      {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
     <button type="submit">Save</button>
  </form>

   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" 
 integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"> 
</script>
  <script>
    $("#id_productcategory").change(function () {
    var url = $("#designerForm").attr("data-subcategories-url");
     var productcategoryId = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        data: {
          'productcategory': productcategoryId
        },
       success: function (data) {
         $("#id_subcategory").html(data);
       }
      });

     });
   </script>

{% endblock %}
```

city_dropdown_list_options.jinja

```
 <option value="">---------</option>
 {% for subcategory in subcategories %}
 <option value="{{ subcategory.pk }}">{{ subcategory.name }}</option>
 {% endfor %}
```

[image: errorimage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SubCategory` model you have a field named `country` which refers to `ProductCategory`. You can't filter with `productcategory_id` because there is no such column/field in current model.

```
 class SubCategory(models.Model):
     country = models.ForeignKey(ProductCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So try to fix your queries like below in `forms.py` and `views.py` :

```
SubCategory.objects.filter(country_id=productcategory_id).order_by('name')
```